# DokuWiki: Automatic keyword detection and linking to existing pages

Tags: plugins, hyperlink, wiki, dokuwiki

I have a portable DokuWiki set up on my computer. Release 2014-09-29d "Hrun".
I have range of pages already created on multiple topics. I wanted to know whether it is possible for the Wiki/Plugin to automatically detect keywords and link them to existing pages.

For example: If I have a page name "cat" then if I mention "cat" anywhere on a new page I would like it to link the keyword to that page. Is this possible?

I have tried to use AutoLink3 however I was unsuccessful as it doesn't seem to work as described.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [CamelCase links](https://www.dokuwiki.org/config:camelcase) is what you are looking for.